# jQueryUI Dialog is incorrectly showing text under the Close Button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jQuery 3 and jQueryUI 1.12. After upgrading, I'm getting this when I show the dialog:

[image]

The glitch is that the word "Close" is appearing under the close button.

The reason for this is that it's actually in the generated HTML that way:

[image]

But I can't figure out why it's doing this or how to fix it (other than by hacking the DOM directly, but that seems undesirable since it's a core part of the library).

What's going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Normally jQuery UI is applying the rule `.ui-button-icon-only` with `text-indent: -9999px;` to that. As per your html the class is there. So make sure you have the jQuery UI css included (with the package for the dialog) and that no custom rules are overriding it.

Comment: Brilliant, and fast. Thanks for this. This led me to some mismatched stylesheets, which fixed my problem. If you post as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI uses it's own stylesheet for the dialog.
The standard css-rule applying for that element is `.ui-button-icon-only` which sets `text-indent: -9999px;`

Make sure you have included `jquery-ui.css`. When using the [download-builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/) make sure the styles for the dialog are included. And the correct theme is selected.

To make changed to the default styles you can use the [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)